# How to send request URL to subdomain site for authenticate user

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, .htaccess

I'm looking ways to send async request URL to subdomain site for authenticate user when user visit special page of main website

The main website domain - https://example.com is on Wordpress.
The web server is Apache.
The subdomain is https://api.example.com.
URL has template: https://api.example.com/key/ABCDEFG

If I open this URL in my web-browser, the user authentication is okay.

I've already on my wordpress site in function.php next code:

```html
  
add_action('wp', 'auth_in_platform', 10, 1);

function auth_in_platform()
{
   if (is_page('api'))
   {
     //here I have my manipulation to make api_url
    
    //api_url ready for request
    $api_url = 'https://api.example.com/key/ABCDEFG';
              
    //what's next ?
              
   }
}
```

In summary, I stopped by 2 big questions:

1) I think maybe this code maybe useful, but don't know how make async for wordpress and launch it right way:

```
   
var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
x.withCredentials = true;
x.open("GET", api_url, true);
x.onload = function ()
{
  //alert(this.responseText);
  //alert(web_url);
}

x.onerror = function() 
{
  //alert( 'Error ' + this.status );
}

x.send(null);
```

2) And how could I enable cross domain requests to send and to receive on origin domain and on requested subdomain ?

Or maybe you can make another proposition to solve the task.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Doesn't anybody know ?

Comment: Is it really hard ?

Comment: Really, nodoby know about this features ? Dear developers from Google and Apple, where are you ?